# Save list to to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created a function on my restaurant review site that finds the cuisine of the last review and then finds other reviews of the same cuisines with a greater average score and then saves the restaurant id of those reviews into a table on the database. However I keep on getting the error:

> Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable.

on the line `restaurantid = choices`.Any help would be grateful.

```
var averagescore = db.Reviews
                     .Where(r => r.Cuisine == review.Cuisine)
                     .Average(r => r.score);

var choices = (from r in db.Reviews
               where r.score <= averagescore
               select r.RestaurantId).ToList;

foreach (var item in choices)
{
    var suggestion = new Suggestion()
    {
        id = review.id,
        Userid = review.UserId,
        restaurantid = choices
    };

    db.Suggestions.Add(suggestion);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: you are assigning list<id> to id in the line   restaurantid = choices

Comment: Did you mean to do: `restaurantid = item` ?

Comment: What type is `restaurantid` at all?

Comment: @HeinA.Grønnestad: since he's selecting `RestaurantID` i assume that he just needs `restaurantid = item`. It would be a good idea to change the variable name from `item` to `choiceRestaurantId`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yeah, just saw it and edited right before your comment ;)

Comment: I can't help but notice that you REALLY shouldn't be saving `suggestion` to the database. You could be pulling `suggestion` out of the database dynamically each run to avoid caching issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following line:

```
var choices = (from ...).ToList;
```

Should be:

```
var choices = (from ...).ToList();
```

Secondly, it looks to me that `restaurantid` is of type `int`. With your code you're assigning a `List<int>` to the int. This should be `item`, from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the following change:

```
var averagescore = db.Reviews
                     .Where(r => r.Cuisine == review.Cuisine)
                     .Average(r => r.score);

var choices = (from r in db.Reviews
               where r.score <= averagescore
               select r.RestaurantId).ToList;

foreach (var item in choices)
{
    var suggestion = new Suggestion()
    {
        id = review.id,
        Userid = review.UserId,
        restaurantid = item //here was your problem, you need to assign an id not a list of ids
    };

    db.Suggestions.Add(suggestion);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this:

```
var choices = (from r in db.Reviews
                    where r.score <= averagescore
                    select r).ToList;
    foreach (var item in choices)
            {
             var suggestion = new Suggestion()
                            {
                             id = item.id,
                             Userid = item.UserId,
                             restaurantid = item.Restaurantid
                             };
                             db.Suggestions.Add(suggestion);
                             db.SaveChanges();
            }
```